# NSIS: Default installation path

Tags: installation, nsis

How can I add a default path (e.g. C:\Program Files...) to installer. (I mean a hard-coded variable, for example, for it.)

Thanks all in advance...

Comment: What do you want to do? You want to hardcode the destination directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `$INSTDIR` to an arbitrary value:

```
StrCpy $INSTDIR "c:\program files\my folder"
```

Comment: OK, but why doesn't it work correctly: default path is randomly changed when I install my application. I set install path to _@CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT@\@CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY@_ and it must install to _C:\program files\my folder_. But randomly default path is set to another: _C:\users\<user>\documents and settings_ for Win7 when installation is done even by local administrator.

Comment: @andrey_sz: do you use `SetOutPath` somewhere? If not, you should put a `SetOutPath $INSTDIR` before the `File` statements of your installed files.

Comment: One should probably use `StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES\my folder"` instead. That is, avoid using literal program path, as it might be changed at the operating system level.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević: you are right, but the OP explicitely asked about an hardcoded value in his question :o)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to copy some string into $INSTDIR.

You can simply use this:

```
; The default installation directory
InstallDir "C:\Program Files\my_sw"
```